# Apache NS rewrite flag has no effect

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I’m trying to wrap my head around Apache’s NS rewrite rule flag. The [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ns) says that applying the flag to any rule causes it not to be interpreted on subrequests, i. e. internal requests initiated by the server rather than the user.

Still, trying `RewriteRule !\.html$ static%{REQUEST_URI} [NS]` which is supposed to internally redirect all URLs not ending with the .html extension to be served from the `static/` folder results in an infinite loop of redirects.

Am I missing the point here? If this flag is not meant to prevent a rule to be interpreted on subsequent rounds, is explicitly negating the rewritten path in the first argument the only way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure not the [`L`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) flag is the one you need?

To see why it enters the infinite loop turn on [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and maybe lower the [`RewriteLogLevel`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel).

Comment: The `L` flag only skips further rules in the current loop. Using the C analogy, `L` is the `continue` while `NS` is the `break` statement. Also, the logs clearly show what causes the problem, namely that new internal requests result in a URL `/static/static/static/.../static/test.txt` exceeding the limit. The only thing it does not show is why.

Answer (score 0):

could you check that the server doesn't externally redirects you?
because if it does an external redirect, then the NS flag is useless.
the other thing could be that you have more rules than this one, and the infinite loop is caused by that.

Tyrael

Comment: It does no external redirect. This is a test ruleset, the only thing in the `.htaccess` file aside the rule above is the `RewriteEngine on` directive.

Comment: I've came across a good [article](http://www.colder.ch/news/01-26-2007/24/truth-about-the-last-mod_.html)

could this be related to your problem? could you check out what happens if you move your rewrite stuff to the apache config instead of the .htaccess file?